# Mysql Delete between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete details between two dates

My code is given below

```
Delete from emp_leave_details 
where emp_id='$id' 
and from_date BETWEEN '$f_date' AND '$t_date'
```

The problem is that it deleted all record between `$f_date` and `$t_date` but didn't delete the record of `$t_date` .I want to delete the records from `$t_date` also.

Comment: `from_data >= '$f_date' AND from_date <= '$t_date'`

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/5080824/mysql-between-clause-not-inclusive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

```
Delete from emp_leave_details 
where emp_id='$id' 
and DATE(from_date) BETWEEN DATE('$f_date') AND DATE('$t_date')
```

### Explanation

Yours query is equal to `from_date >= '$f_date' AND from_date <= '$t_date'`, meaning it will ignore all that last day `('2013-09-05' < '2013-09-05 00:00:01')`. Mine above gives `('2013-09-05' <= '2013-09-05')` instead.

`DATE()` simply strips the values of hours, minutes and seconds and gives you expected result since `BETWEEN` uses `<=` and `>=`.

Comment: Its working if i run in MySql server but same is not working from my php code ? please help                                                                                                                        Delete from tablename where date ('2014-12-05') BETWEEN DATE('2014-12-05') AND DATE('2014-12-08')

Comment: Try removing space after `date`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
Delete from emp_leave_details 
  Where emp_id='$id' 
   AND from_data > '$f_date' 
   AND from_date <= '$t_date';
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a `datetime` column then using the date will not suffice since `2013-09-25 12:00:00` is **greater** than `2013-09-25`

You can you this

```
Delete from emp_leave_details 
Where emp_id = '$id' 
and from_date >= '$f_date' 
and from_date < '$t_date'
```

and set `'$t_date'` to 1 day later.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you also include an id in your query, but answering to your question directly, you should

```
Delete from emp_leave_details
  Where emp_id='$id'
  and from_date > '$f_date'
  and from_date <= '$t_date'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("Delete from emp_leave_details Where emp_id='$id' and (from_date BETWEEN '$f_date' AND '$t_date'");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that for the $t_date, it starts at 00:00:00. That is the beginning of the day. Everything during the day is not included. 
If you want to include the records of $t_date, you should ***add 1*** to it.

```
$t_date = $t_date + 1
```